# Making diagnal lines flattened on the vertical with SVG

Tags: svg

I have a symbol similar to a letter "V". The end points of the "V" are slanted as in the left-side picture below. However, I would like them to be flattened on the horizontal as in the right-side picture below. How can I do this?

My SVG code looks like this:

```
<svg width="120" height="120" viewPort="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polyline points="30,30 60,90 90,30" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="25" />
</svg>
```

[image]

Image I currently have      . . . . . . .  Image I want to have

Comment: A very crude solution would be `<polyline points="17.5,-12.5 60,90 102.5,-12.5" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="25" />`. It starts the line from outside the viewing area, the areas outside are cut (like `overflow: hidden`) and so it will look like the image you want. But I'm not posting that as an answer because to me it feels more like a workaround than a solution. If no other better solution comes up, I'll post it as an answer. (12.5 is nothing but stroke-width/2)

Comment: Load the file into an SVG editor such as inkscape and adjust the shape.

Answer (score 0):

A proper way to create the required shape would be to use a `polygon` or `path` element and fill it.

### Approach 1 - Polygon:

SVG's `polygon` elements takes single argument i.e `points` which contains a list of points. It then create a shape by joining all these points and filling them.

Here is necessary code:

```
<polygon points="15,30 40,30 60,70 80,30 105,30 60,120" />
```

**Working Example:**

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewPort="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="15,30 40,30 60,70 80,30 105,30 60,120" />
</svg>
```

### Approach 2 - Path:

SVG's `path` element takes only one required attribute i.e `d`. This attribute contains a series of commands and respective arguments to describe a shape.

Here is necessary code:

```
<path d="M15,30 h25 L60,70 80,30 h25 L60,120 z" />
```

**Working Example:**

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewPort="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M15,30 h25 L60,70 80,30 h25 L60,120 z" />
</svg>
```

**Result:**

[image: V Shape]